# JavaScript- How to find an element and return its path in an array recursively?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Data structure look like this

```
[{id: 1,
  items:[{ id: 2,
            items: [ id: 3]
           },

          { id: 4,
           items:[id: 5]
          }]
},
{
id: 6,
items:[{ id: 7,
         items: [ id: 8]
       },

       {id: 9,
        items:[id: 10]
       }]
}]
```

I want to find an element by its `id`, and return its path including its parents' path

For example, if `id=10`, the path of the 10 is `6.9.10`

```
findId(array, id, path,pathList){

        array.map(i => {

            if(i.items == undefined){
                return;
            }


            path = path + '.' +item.id;
            pathList.push(path);

            if(i.id == id){
                return pathList;
            }else{
                pathList.pop();
                this.findId(i.fields, id, path, pathList);

            }
        })

    }
```

My question is, how to find `id=10` and return an array which contains `[6, 6.9, 6.9.10]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Sorry about that! Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow my method:

```js
var obj = [{id: 1,
  items:[{ id: 2,
            items: [{id: 3}]
           },

          { id: 4,
           items:[{id: 5}]
          }]
},
{
id: 6,
items:[{ id: 7,
         items: [{id: 8}]
       },

       {id: 9,
        items:[{id: 10}]
       }]
}];
function searchId(object, index_to_find){
  //first, add depth (of each element) to array items
  var depths = object;
  //structure of path = [[0,length_1st],[1,length_2nd],[2,length_3rd],[3,length_4th],...,[last,length_last]]
  var path = [];
  //for first value of path
  path.push([0,depths.length]);
  //test to add depth for depths:
  depths.map(function add_depth(current){
    current['depth'] = path[path.length-1][0];
    if(current.items){
      //continue to array items
      path.push([path[path.length-1][0]+1,current.items.length]);
      current.items.map(add_depth);
    }else{
      //get back of path
      while(path.length>1 && path[path.length-1][1]<2){
          path.pop();
      }
      //decrease length path[...[x,length]]
      path[path.length-1][1]--;
    };
  });
  //console.log(depths);
  var path_result = [];
  var flagFound = false;
  depths.findIndex(function find_id(current,index){
      if (flagFound){
          return;
      };
      if(current.id===index_to_find){
          //finish at here
          path_result[current.depth] = index;
          flagFound = true;
          return;
      }else{
          if(current.items){
              path_result[current.depth] = index;
              current.items.findIndex(find_id);
          };
      };
  });
  if(!flagFound)
    return undefined;
  //console.log(path_result);
  var self_items;
  var path_end = "";
  var result_end = [];
  if(path_result){
    for(i=0;i<path_result.length;i++){
      if(i==0){
        let temp_id = object[path_result[i]].id;
        path_end = path_end + temp_id;
        result_end.push(path_end);
        self_items = object[path_result[i]].items;
      }else if(i==path_result.length-1){
        let temp_id = self_items[path_result[i]].id;
        path_end = path_end + "." + temp_id;
        result_end.push(path_end);
      }else{
        let temp_id = self_items[path_result[i]].id;
        path_end = path_end + "." + temp_id;
        result_end.push(path_end);
        self_items = self_items[path_result[i]].items;
      };
    }
  };
  //console.log(path_end);
  return result_end;
};
console.log(searchId(obj,10));
console.log(searchId(obj,8));
```